# Cannot see user created folders in Visual Studio Open folder dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created a folder under Windows\system32 with a config file in it. For some reason when I browse to that folder with the Visual Studio Open folder dialog the folder does not exist. You can certainly navigate to it via explorer or any other way you want to. Is there anything special about this location that causes this? BTW: I am on Windows Server 2008 R2 and using VS2010.

TIA!

Comment: I'm guessing you are running this on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Which uses file system redirection for 32-bit processes, like Visual Studio.  You'll end up looking in c:\windows\syswow64 instead.  Do not create folders in c:\windows\system32.  The c:\windows directory is reserved for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hans: I'm guessing you are running this on a 64-bit version of Windows. Which uses file system redirection for 32-bit processes, like Visual Studio. You'll end up looking in c:\windows\syswow64 instead. Do not create folders in c:\windows\system32. The c:\windows directory is reserved for Windows.